# Java ArrayList class cast exception when trying to set an member variable for an instance of a class

Tags: java, arraylist, classcastexception

Hi I have been stuck on this error for the past 3 hours and will probably slap myself when somebody figures out what is wrong. I am really just trying to set an ArrayList to an instance of my TeacherAccount class. i keep getting the below error when running the simplest test I think I can which is also below.

Here is the TeacherAccount class

```
package com.studentOrganizer;


import java.util.List;

public class TeacherAccount {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private List<String> students;

    public TeacherAccount(){
        username=null;
        password=null;
        students = null;

    }
    public TeacherAccount(String username, String password,List<String> students){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.students = students;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<String> students){
        this.students = students;  
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

    public List<String> getStudents() {
        return students;  
    }
}
```

And here is the small test I am running that produces the error

```
            TeacherAccount currentTeach = new TeacherAccount();
        List<String> tempStu = new ArrayList<String>();
        tempStu.add("Hi");
        tempStu.add("Hi again");
        currentTeach.setStudents(tempStu);
```

I have narrowed it down the the problem being the setStudents. tempStu and students are both of type List Any help is appreciated. Thanks

EDIT Here is the JSP file as requested:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<% String currentUsername = (String)request.getAttribute("currentUsername"); %>
<% String currentPassword = (String)request.getAttribute("currentPassword"); %>
<% String students = (String)request.getAttribute("students"); %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/StudentOrganizer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<title>Student Organization Home Page</title>

</head>
<body>
<form action="">
<div class='header'>Student Organization Home Page - Welcome <%=currentUsername%>!</div>
</form>

 <br>
 <div>Test for jsp vars <%=currentUsername%> PASS: <%=currentPassword%> STUDENTS: <%=students%></div>

<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="jsp/students.jsp">
    <select>
        <option selected>Class 1</option>
        <option selected>Class 2</option>
        <option selected>Class 3</option>
        <option selected>Class 4</option>
    </select>
    <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Go To Students!">
    </FORM>
</body>

</html>


[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com._jsp._homepage._jspService:98'
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com._jsp._homepage._jspService(_homepage.java:98)
    at com.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:101)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:215)
    at com.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1033)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.studentOrganizer.Login.doGet(Login.java:93)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at [internal classes]

[err] java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
[err]   at com._jsp._homepage._jspService(_homepage.java:98)
[err]   at com.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:101)
[err]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[err]   at [internal classes]
```

Comment: The problem seems to be in some JSP page that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use the three-arg constructor instead of the default constructor>

Comment: @jlordo `_homepage.java` is what the `homepage.jsp` compiles to inside his (tomcat?) server. The small test is probably in his jsp. **Drew - if this assumption is incorrect say so!**

Comment: @corsiKa: Ok, (haven't worked with JSP yet). Anyway, the assumption that the code he showed us is not causing the problem is correct.

Comment: Please post some more code. Your assumption of the lines causing the problem may not be correct.

Comment: I have included the jsp file

Comment: @RohitJain Wouldn't any sane page renderer use `toString()` instead of casting.

Comment: @S.D.. Well, `request.getAttribute` returns an `Object`. SO, no it won't work that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not strong in JSP but what clear for me , you try to show `students` in JSP file like single String. But `students` is defined as List. please, run in loop in JSP file on your Students.

Something like:

```
<%
ArrayList<String> students = teacherAccount .getStudents();
    Iterator<String> iterator = students .iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
      String student = (String)iterator.next();
      String pId = String.getId();
      ...
%>
```

Suppose your problem is here:

```
<div>Test for jsp vars <%=currentUsername%> 
PASS: <%=currentPassword%> STUDENTS: <%=students%></div>
                                           ^^^^
```

Use `forEach` instead to show it

Comment: This is correct. An alternative, which would be less pretty but would probably get you a decent grade, is `students.toString()`, if you can do that. Otherwise, you could put a tiny scriptlet in that did `<% out.write(students); %>`

Comment: Thank you!! did not notice that. This solution worked for me.